# substr and mb_strcut not working as expected

Tags: php, string, cut, substr

I am trying to cut last 11 character of this string:

```php
$tmp = "La Liga Resumos da Jornada T.1 Ep.22 00:00 01:30";

$titulo = substr($tmp, 0, -11);
// or
$titulo = mb_strcut($tmp, -11, "UTF-8");
```

but result only cut last 5 character no mather a increase len to cut.

ex: La Liga Resumos da Jornada T.1 Ep.22 00:00

anyone have an ideia?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://3v4l.org/lXDgb - and you're using [mb_​strcut](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strcut.php) wrong